# OPS Hub - unable to migrate project

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to migrate one project from tfs on prem to VSTSO . I am getting the following error 
[Ops Hub error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdGWq.png)

I have  successfully migrated couple of projects before but this one wont go .  I did notice one thing when i was migrating . It gave different name to the default collection as you see in the screen shot . I have deleted the account and recreated the account and still getting the same.Please advise.
thanks

Comment: Hi Navdeep, 
Please let us know, if any proxy is configured in your instance. Also, please send application logs to support@opshub.com. So our agent would follow up with you and assist you to resolve the issue.
You would find logs at <Utility Installation folder>/logs
Regards,
OpsHub Support

Comment: Hi - i don't have a proxy configured . I also tried to clear the cache but the sam result . I sent out the log to you guys . Please advise. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be a recent change in VSTS as Nicolas pointed out. Currently, the OVSMU tool will not be usable directly. We would be releasing a patched version early next week which will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Update]: This change is part of the following change annoncement: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/2016-apr-13-vso

I've been able to solve this "page not found" exception by using fiddler and the following rule: oSession.url = oSession.url.Replace("/NameOfTheCollection/Services/v3.0/","/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/"); But I face another issue on HubOps.

Finally, I used TFS migration tools + fiddler rule described above and I'm able to move forward on this migration.

Another option is to contact microsoft in order to ask for early acces of TFS - VSO migration tool: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2264946-import-data-from-tfs-on-prem-into-vs-team-services

BR