# Migration Utility giving error for Visual Studio Team Services Project Collection URL

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to see how the `OpsHub` migration tool works before I perform real migration.

And hence I am trying with a on premise TFS instance and a trial created Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) instance. but when I finish configuring the stuff and it start to validate all the settings put in, it is giving error for Team Services Project Collection URL. It is taking collection URL as

> https://********.visualstudio.com/********

where as it should only use

> https://********.visualstudio.com/

Not sure how to get over it and now fully stuck.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of OVSMU? This recent change in VSTS was handled in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the change in VSTS:

> **Collection in the domain**
>
> Your Team Services account URL just got 18 characters shorter. We’ve
>   removed “/DefaultCollection” from the path. While it’s small, but
>   welcome change. It’s the beginning of a larger journey to how we
>   structure accounts. Learn more here.
>
> Note that existing accounts will still give out the longer URL for Git
>   Clones in the Code hub. This is because to use the new shorter URL in
>   VS, you will need to reconnect Team Explorer using the shorter URL.
>   Today you either need to use the long or the short URL for an account
>   in VS, you can’t intermingle. Once we have enough clients updated such
>   that they just work seamlessly with either type, we’ll change the
>   default Git Clone URL to the shorter one as well.
>
> Last but not least, we have a set of Release Management improvements.

Please download the latest version of OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility and then try again.

A similar issue here: [OPS Hub - unable to migrate project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851053/ops-hub-unable-to-migrate-project).